How can I update new command of Mathematica?
This is my code
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\ProvidesPackage{latexalpha2Win}
\lstset{language=Mathematica}
\lstset{basicstyle={\sffamily\footnotesize},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos={t},
    frame={lines},
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    framerule=0.5pt,
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
        SolveValues[Sqrt[8  x^2 - 3  x - 10] == -2 + 3  x, x, Reals]
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

I got

SolveValues is updated in 2023. How can I bold SolveValues like Sqrt?

What's the relationship between SolValues and SolveValues?

Have you tried adding ,morekeywords={SolveValues} -- or, as the case may be, ,morekeywords={SolValues} -- to the argument of \lstset?

@cfr I am sorry. It must be SolveValues.

@Mico It works fine. Thank you very much. I input by my hand new command of Mathematica.
